# ChannelShell setPty(true) or setPty(false), different InputStream read type

Tags: java, linux, sockets, ssh, jsch

When I setPty(true), I can directly use in.available() to get the number of bytes that can be read.

When I setPty(false), I have to use in.read() first and then use in.available() to get the number of bytes of remains.

I think JSch always use socket connect to SSH Server.
Who can tell me why is the setPty(true) or setPty(false) have the different for use InputStream.

Comment: *"I think JSch always use socket connect to SSH Server"* – Yes. But that's for the top level raw TCP connection only. But the streams in the "channel" API are not socket streams. Those are virtual streams tunneled through the encrypted socket stream. And in general JSch channel streams are far from being perfect `Stream` implementations.

Comment: Thank you  Martin Prikryl. I think I get a different reason.